# Main differences between xsl:copy, xsl:next-match and xsl:copy-of

Tags: xslt

Please suggest the main differences between these XSLT functions, where results are same for these three functions for the below input and XSLT code (remove comment and execute). Suggest the particular importance of usage of these functions. Are these functions are differed in namespaces area. (XSLT2)

Input xml:

```
<root>
  <a>The text a1
      <b>The text b1</b>
      <b>The text b2
          <c>The text c1</c>
      </b>
          <c>The text c2</c>
   </a>
</root>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<!--xsl:template match="b">
    <xsl:element name="B"><xsl:next-match/></xsl:element>
</xsl:template-->

<!--xsl:template match="b">
    <xsl:element name="B"><xsl:copy-of select="."/></xsl:element>
</xsl:template-->

<xsl:template match="b">
    <xsl:element name="B">
       <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/></xsl:copy>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You currently cannot see a difference between your approaches because your example is still too simple. Let's describe the difference between `<xsl:copy-of>` and `<apply-templates>` first: `<xsl:copy>` makes a **literal** copy of the context node `.` which is for example:

```
<b>The text b2
   <c>The text c1</c>
</b>
```

In the literal copy the XSLT processor does not check anymore if there are any matching rules for the child tag `<c>`. They are simply ignored.
The tag `<xsl:apply-templates>` however, applies all available template rules to any given depth, so if you had a rule for `<c>` it would be applied.

Hence: to see the difference between those first two options create a template match for `<c>` which *does not* make a literal copy of it.

Understanding the use of `<xslt:next-match>` is slightly more difficult. It requires you to know what the **next best possible template match** would be at the point that you call it. In your case, since you only have the default copy rule

```
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

next to the specific rule for `<b>` the default rule would be the *next best one*. And, of course the default rule does nothing else but copy the sub tree again using the `<apply-templates>`, so that you do not see any difference.

In order to see a difference there it would be necessary for rule to create a rule for `<b>` that is *less specific than the one present* but at the same time *more specific* that the default rule. This will probably be hard to do.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Even <b> nested by another <b>, then two functions are resulting the same.

Comment: The question seems a bit like asking what's the difference beween addition and multiplication and exponentiation, given that 2+2, 2*2, and 2^2 all give the same answer.

Comment: Right Sir, if <b> nested by another <b> (even further level of nesting also), in such cases, 'NEXT-MATCH and <XSL:COPY><XSL:APPLY-TEMPLATES select="@*|NODE()"/></XSL:COPY> will produce the same results, then what is the main DIFFERENCE between these two, irrespective of my inputs.